# Logging or a logger class that will print the log message with a custom prefix

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project that has multiple classes. I want to streamline my logging process so that I can create some custom ostream object `log` so that wherever I want to print a log message, I can write `log << my-message`. The catch is that each of my class has a name (stored as a string) and I want the ostream object to prefix the name of the class before the log message. So the output would look like:

```
name-of-class: my-message
```

How can I do this in C++?

I tried create a Logger class with a name variable, and then instantiating an object of that class in each of my classes, which will then set the class' name as the Logger object's name. But this approach cannot scale because once I concatenate multiple log messages, the name gets printed each time.

I also tried using variadic templates/functions, but then I wasn't able to pass in arguments such as `std::hex`, `std::endl`, etc.

Comment: Well, you need a flush marker like `std::endl` or `std::flush`, and you will buffer the log messages until flushed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment? Sorry, but I do not understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: `log << "something=" << 5 << logger::flush;` to write "something=5" as single log entry is what I mean.

Comment: Oh yes, I think I can try that. Thank you

Comment: you should accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Sorry I am new to asking questions here. I accepted the answer by 0x499602D2 below. I don't know how to accept the comment by @hyde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can work directly on the stream buffer you won't have to redefine the copious extractors/inserters to get the functionality you want. What this basically boils down to is using a flag to determine if the initial log message name should be printed. The flag flips to false once we write it.

The logger should be accessed using `logger()` so that it can reset the variables.

```c++
struct : std::streambuf {
  std::ostream* os = &std::cout;
  std::string msg;
  bool insert;
  void str(std::string const& s) { msg = s; }
  int_type overflow(int_type c) override {
    if (insert) {
      (*os) << msg;
      insert = false;
    }
    return os->rdbuf()->sputc(c);
  }
  int sync() override { return os->rdbuf()->pubsync(); }
} logbuf;

std::ostream& logger(std::string const& msg = "Message from me: ") {
  logbuf.insert = true;
  logbuf.str(msg);
  static std::ostream os(&logbuf);
  return os;
}

int main() {
  logger() << "1"
           << " + "
           << "1 = " << 2 << '\n';
  logger() << 3 << " - " << 3 << " = " << 0 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> Message from me: 1 + 1 = 2
>   Message from me: 3 - 3 = 0

Comment: Thanks ‭@0x499602D2